# Word for "butting in on the Net"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm not sure if **rubbernecking** is the term I should be using, but what do you call the act of commenting on an Internet discussion, just for the sake of letting other people know that you want to butt in, but not actually add anything to the discussion.

An example of this would be watching a heated argument on Facebook and you adding a comment, "Pass the popcorn", which is pretty annoying and does not actually add anything to the discussion.

Comment: After looking at the definition of _Rubbernecking_, I think that it doesn't fit with your intended usage.

Comment: Yeah, but that's the closest thing I can think of. I'm not really good with vocabulary.

Comment: spamming. see also, next comment.

Comment: "Pass the pop corn!"

Comment: It's not for nothing that those starred-out/ double-slashed-out lines are called 'comments'.

Answer (score 4):

Deliberately trying to irk people on the Net and trying to create controversy goes under the name of **trolling**.

> To make a conscious attempt to provoke controversy or disagreement on the Internet (Chambers)

Any person who passes such uncalled-for remarks that are not in line with the discussion are called **trolls**. [This Wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troll_%28Internet%29) provides all details about trolling.

Comment: +1. Close but not correct. Frivolous, hollow, 'filler' comments as in OP's example may not count as trolling.

Comment: @Kris: Not according to the dictionary, but Wiki (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troll_%28Internet%29) does agree with me. Time for an update to the dict!

Comment: But first an update to your answer right here :-)

Answer (score 3):

The most obvious verb for such activity is to
*[kibitz](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kibitz)* ("To chat; to gossip; to make small talk or idle chatter" or "To give unsolicited or unwanted advice or make unhelpful or idle comments, especially to someone playing a game").  Also consider to *[snark](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snark)* ("To express oneself in a snarky fashion", *ie* to make snide remarks or offer sarcasm), and aforementioned *troll*.  I've also seen such comments referred to as *[drive-bys](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/drive-by#English)* (things "done quickly or in a cursory manner") and as *[flame bait](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flame_bait)* ("(Internet) deliberately provocative posting intended to start a flame war") or *[arson](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arson)* ("The crime of setting a fire with intent to cause damage").

Comment: +1 for *kibitz* -- that fits the bill. About the only word in your list that suits, in fact.

Comment: What we need is an e-kibitz, so to speak.